# How do I dynamically add to a vector drawable?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I've created a dial gauge and have managed to get the dial to rotate. In the 1st example image below, the dial gauge shows 5 tick marks (these were hard coded in the drawable xml file). If I wanted to dynamically create these tick marks (let's say I wanted a different number of tick marks), how would I go about doing so? I would think that I would need to start with a blank dial gauge (shown in the 2nd image), and then would programmatically add the tick marks via java.

[image: Dial gauge]
[image: Blank dial gauge]

Comment: Maybe use a single tick image and copy then rotate it before overlaying it to the existing graphics.

Comment: Right, that would be another option, however, the actual process of handling that is escaping me at the moment. A simple working example or a reference to a working example would help me immensely.

Comment: or... another way would be to have a layerlist (already populated with the maximum number of items - i.e.: each rotated at an angle of 10°) and set the individual items visibility. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable But I'm afraid this approach wouldn't be very efficient.